# Animation for Button's Pressed VisualState doesn't fire

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visualstatemanager

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 project. My issue with this button:

```
        <Button x:Name="decreaseFontButton" Foreground="{StaticResource GlobalBrush}">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="decreaseFontButton">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="70"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="decreaseFontButton" Completed="ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames_Completed_1">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource GlobalBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="/Assets/Player/sub_minus.png" Width="28" Height="28"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

is that none of the two animations gets trigged. I tried to change VisualStateGroup's name to **FocusState** and VisualState's name to **Focused**, but I didn't saw any change either. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I appreciate your attention!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your storyboard, just how you're trying to invoke it. It just needs to be made a control template and declared a resource. I would suggest looking at a default button template and how it uses VisualStateManager, if that doesn't expose your answer pretty quick we can show you what you're missing pretty easily but you're not far off.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I've already did this, the visual result became as expected, but I still didn't find out why initial solution is not good.

Comment: It's just because a VisualStateManager can't be applied directly to a UIElement, just has to be in a control template for the UIElement TargetType. No big deal, glad you found your remedy. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you're trying to modify the Visual States. These are actually part of the inner template of the button and not configurable in the way you are trying.

Instead you should look to create a new style which includes the visual state changes you want and they applying that style to the button.

Like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush Color="Aqua" x:Key="aquabrush" />

    <Style x:Key="AlternativeButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource aquabrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="70"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates"/>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Button Content="pressed?" Style="{StaticResource AlternativeButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```